# Django: CSS not extended for some pages?

Tags: python, css, django, extend

I'm trying to learn Django using the online version of the "Test-Driven Development with Python" book. I have a base.html file and home.html and list.html file. Now, CSS works fine for home.html, but not at all for list.html! They both extend their CSS from the base.html file, so why is there a problem? Here are the files:

**base.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>To-Do lists</title>
        <link href="static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <h1>{% block header_text %}{% endblock %}</h1>
                        <form method="POST" action="{% block form_action %}{% endblock %}">
                            <input name="item_text" id="id_new_item" placeholder="Enter a to-do item"/>
                            {% csrf_token %}
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                    {% block table %}
                    {% endblock %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**home.html:**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block header_text %}Start a new To-Do list{% endblock %}

{% block form_action %}/lists/new{% endblock %}
```

**list.html:**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block header_text %}Your To-Do list{% endblock %}

{% block form_action %}/lists/{{ list.id }}/add_item{% endblock %}

{% block table %}
    <table id="id_list_table">
        {% for item in list.item_set.all %}
            <tr><td>{{ forloop.counter }}: {{ item.text }}</td></tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

It's probably something silly, but anyway, thank you!

Comment: what errors are you getting, if any, in the web console inside the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using hard coded 
CSS links

```
<link href="static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Use Django Template Tags:

Or you can also use below if you list.html is rendering `yoursite.com/list/`

```
<link href="../static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

if yoursite.com/something/list/ then use;

```
<link href="../../static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: you can also use django template tag for static links
<link href={% static "static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" %} rel="stylesheet"> 
Peace!!